# Why fetch data in `load` when I can fetch data in `{#await}` or `onMount` which hit `+server` in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

keyword: show spinner

Suppose when I hit a route, e.g. `/dashboard`, most of the page content is static but a few sub-components need real time data. If I fetch data in a `load` function, the whole route can't display anything until data is ready.

Alternatively, I can fetch data in `onMount` or `{#await}` with the benefit of showing a spinner. (if the fetching must happen on server side, I can fetch from an api route)

So when is the `load` good? Is it just for clients with slow internet and clients without javascript, and for SEO?

Answer (score 1):

Don't blame the client, your application might be too slow if you need a spinner

Of course there are cases where things might take longer, and something like that might be appropriate, but there often are things that come from the server that are fast to load which saves a round trip which would even be delayed by the rest of the page loading in.

E.g. data about the current user required for some user menu/avatar should not need to block the rest of the page.

I would

- See how long something takes to load and if it hardly registers use `load` (page or layout)
- Possibly optimize it if it is slow and can be optimized
- Load separately if it really has to remain slow

Answer (score 1):

You should use `load()` for *essential* data. `onMount()` requires JavaScript, so it will not be called if JavaScript is disabled or otherwise broken.

You may use `onMount()` if you are OK with the data not always being loaded. (In your case, it will just be "stuck" at the loading spinner. Try disabling JS to see what it would look like.)

---

[Streaming with promises](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises), an alternative to the `onMount()` method you described, just [landed in SvelteKit](https://svelte.dev/blog/streaming-snapshots-sveltekit). It allows you to `await` long-running promises from +page.svelte (if the promise is not at the top-level). Note this requires both JavaScript and a platform that supports streaming (AWS Lambda and similar serverless platforms do not support streaming.)

---

Finally, there may still be a +loading.svelte feature on the SvelteKit roadmap. (I'm not sure if streaming with promises ended up being the feature discussed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4BRVkQVoMc&t=6993s)